# PHP how to adjust price after recieving it through api

Tags: php

Background - The page connects to an api to get some information. When it displays on the page I need to increase the price by 1.25% for the summer season.

This the info from the API:  (this works)

```
<?php
$types = "a,b,c,camper-van";
$vehicles = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.outdoorsy.co/v0/rentals?owner_id=24019&limit=1000&full=true&type=" . $types), true);
$seasons = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.outdoorsy.co/v0/seasons?owner_id=24019&limit=1000"), true);
usort($vehicles, "custom_sort");
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle):
?>
```

This is the displayed section of the page:

```
<p class="fleet-list-item_rates">
   <strong>Sept. 15th – May 14th</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php print(money_format('%.2n', $vehicle["price"]["day"] / 100)) ?> / day &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>*7 Days or More 14% Discount</em>
   <?php
   foreach($seasons as $season):
       $price = find_price_within_season($season, $vehicle["id"]);
       if ($price):
         $day = $price["day"] / 100.0;
       else:
         $day = ($vehicle["price"]["day"] / 100.0) * ($season["adjust_price_percent"] / 100);
       endif;
       ?>
       <br>
       <strong><?php print(friendly_date($season["from"])) ?> - <?php print(friendly_date($season["to"])) ?></strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php print(money_format('%.2n', $day)) ?> / day
<?php endforeach; ?>
</p>
```

This is my edit to add the addition 1.25%

```
    <p class="fleet-list-item_rates">
       <strong>May 14th - Sept. 15th</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php print(money_format('%.2n', $vehicle["price"]["day"] / 100)) ?> / day &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>*7 Days or More 10% Discount</em>
<?php
    $percentagechange = 1.25;
    $numberToAdd = ($price / 100) * $percentagechange;
    $newNumber = $price + $numberToAdd;
    $newNumber = ["newNumber"];
    foreach($seasons as $season):
    $price = find_price_within_season($season, $vehicle["id"]);
    if ($price):
        $day = $price["day"] / 100.0;
    else:
        $day = ($vehicle["price"]["day"] / 100.0) * ($season["newNumber"] / 100);
    endif;
?>
    <br>
    <strong><?php print(friendly_date($season["from"])) ?> - <?php print(friendly_date($season["to"])) ?></strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp; <?php print(money_format('%.2n', $day)) ?> / day
<?php endforeach; ?>
</p>
```

Just at a loss on how to increase the value by 1.25%.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you were calculating the percentage increase before you 
had the actual price.

In terms of how to do the calculation:

```
$percentagechange = 1.25;
$numberToAdd = ($price * $percentagechange) / 100;
$newNumber = $price + $numberToAdd;
// Get rid of the following. It is overwriting your calculated number.
//$newNumber = ["newNumber"];
```

Or

```
$newNumber = $price * 1.0125;
```

How to change your code:

```
if ($price):
    $day = $price["day"] / 100.0;
else:
    $day = ($vehicle["price"]["day"] / 100.0) * ($season["newNumber"] / 100);
endif;
// At this point $day contains the price per day
// Increase price by 1.25%
$day *= 1.0125;
?>
<br>
<strong>
  <?= friendly_date($season["from"]) ?> - <?= friendly_date($season["to"]) ?>
</strong>
  :&nbsp;&nbsp; <?= money_format('%.2n', $day) ?> / day
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note that I changed the code to use `<?=` instead of `<?php print`. They do the same thing except one is shorter than the other.

Comment: OK sorry I still can't get this work work.  More than likely I am adding it to the wrong place.     In the code once I get $newNumber how do I replace $price in the code?

Comment: I thought that you were trying to learn how to make the calculation. I made some changes to the answer which hopefully answered the question.